# How can I implement plt.subplot correctly so my graphs can be side by side?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am outputting two scatter plots, but I want both graphs to be next to each other side by side.

When I use `plt.subplots`, my `ax1` and `ax2` aren't being recognized? How can I make the bottom two scatterplots next to each other? Whenever I use `plt.subplots` it just creates empty graphs.

```
# Scatter plots.
ax1 = df_Baker.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 7))
df_Muriel.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 7), ax=ax1)
df_Tanner.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 7), ax=ax1)


# regression lines
plt.plot(df_Baker.HS_GPA, Baker_fit[0] * df_Baker.HS_GPA + Baker_fit[1], color='darkblue', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(df_Tanner.HS_GPA, Tanner_fit[0] * df_Tanner.HS_GPA + Tanner_fit[1], color='deeppink', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(df_Muriel.HS_GPA, Muriel_fit[0] * df_Muriel.HS_GPA + Muriel_fit[1], color='deeppink', linewidth=2)



plt.legend(labels=['_h', '_hii', '_', '10 - 20','1 - 5'], title='Legend Test')


plt.title('BIO: Basic Concepts', size=24)
plt.xlabel('High school gpa', size=18)
plt.ylabel('cousre Grade', size=18);

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Scatter plots.
ax2 = df_Baker.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(6, 3))
df_Muriel.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(6, 3), ax=ax2)
df_Tanner.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(6, 3), ax=ax2)


# regression lines
plt.plot(df_Baker.HS_GPA, Baker_fit[0] * df_Baker.HS_GPA + Baker_fit[1], color='black', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(df_Tanner.HS_GPA, Tanner_fit[0] * df_Tanner.HS_GPA + Tanner_fit[1], color='black', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(df_Muriel.HS_GPA, Muriel_fit[0] * df_Muriel.HS_GPA + Muriel_fit[1], color='black', linewidth=2)


plt.legend(labels=['_h', '_hii', '_', '10 - 20','1 - 5'], title='Legend Test')


plt.title('BIO: Basic Concepts', size=24)
plt.xlabel('High school gpa', size=18)
plt.ylabel('cousre Grade', size=18);
```

[Output graphs so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yA3p.png)

Comment: Welcome, @Aztec619! 
It would make it easier to help you if you provided a self-contained example of your code, which we could modify in our answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 3))
```

your create the two axes objects and attach the names `ax1` and `ax2` to them.

Later, in

```
ax1 = df_Baker.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 7))
```

(and similarely in the line for `ax2`), your create *new* axis objects, and assign the names `ax1` and `ax2` to them.

I seems that this is not what you want. Rather, I guess you want to use the previously generated axes objects in the calls to `df.Bakker.plot()`. You can achieve this by using the `ax=` keyword:

```
df_Baker.plot(kind='scatter', x='HS_GPA', y='Course_Grade', color='black', alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 7), ax=ax1)
```

You will also have to change the `plt.plot(...)` calls to `ax1.plot(...)` or   `ax2.plot(...)`, and similar for the functions `plt.xlabel`, `plt.ylabel`,  `plt.legend`.

I would suggest to read the Blog post https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/ on the difference between the Pyplot vs. Object Oriented Interface to Matplotlib, and you can also have a look at the examples referenced in https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html